# Можно ли в Yii сохранять письма в папку, как логи

Tags: yii

Есть ли в yii функционал, чтобы не отправлять письма, а сохранять их в папку куда-нибудь, как это реализовано в laravel или как это делает openserver. И как это настроить?
p.s. Проект на yii + docker.

Comment: может локальный сервер почты поднять и отправлять на локалхост? exim например. по умолчанию хранит письма в файлах

Comment: Так это же обычное сохранение в файл.